# Non linear transformation of vector graphic

Tags: c++, vector-graphics

I[image] want to do a non-linear transformation of a svg in python. My specific problem is to transform a rectangular svg image into a frustum like image, for which i have a mathematical equation of the form (x',y') = f(x,y).

So far, I've been able to find a javascript library called warp.js (https://github.com/benjamminf/warpjs), which supports application of generic point-wise transformation on svg. But I'm unable to find any such tools for python or C++ except for basic transformation like skew, rotation etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What you have above is a polar coordinate mapping, you can code it yourself.

Comment: @lightxbulb not entirely trivial though.

Comment: Yeah, I can code it but I can't find any libraries to provide basic tools to code with. I looked into pycairo but it only supports affine transformations. Looked into lib2geom, couldn't understand it's different representations of vector components. The documentation did not seem descriptive enough.